# Qt rendering an image and showing it

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small app that renders an image. It's in .ppm format and opens nicely in Mac's Xee image viewer. The image is created in the default project folder.

However, the user doesn't know where the image is after it is rendered and I would like to open it automatically or perhaps offer where to save the image before it is created.

That is the first problem. The second problem is .ppm - it's not opened by default on Windows, you need Irfan Viewer or something alike.

Is there a way to solve both those problems easily in Qt? For instance, the image is created where the user wants and my app displays it in that ppm format without using some other software? And If a user wants to reopen the image, I should probably make it possible, as well.

I am not a Qt, nor a C++ developer so I am struggling a bit with this, but I have to do it.

Thanks in advance for the tips and advices.

Comment: Qt supports the PPM format, so you can use the I/O functionality of QImage to load and store them. It is pretty straightforward to display a QImage. Just have a look at the Qt docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your image to a `QImage` (if it's not one already), you can specify where and in what format to save it when calling the [`QImage::save`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#save) method.